# How to spawn long-running-processes in Twisted

Tags: twisted, long-running-processes, clips

**Preface**

I'm writing an web-server that gives to users an access to some program written on C (I'm using an Python wrapper over this C-program, it is [PyCLIPS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyclips/)). To serve a lot of users, the web-server has to start a lot of copies of this C-program, because one copy can serve very few users in the same time, about 1-3 users. In addition, each user should work only with his own copy, therefore should be a lot of copies of the C-program.

*This C-program is a [CLIPS engine](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) if it'll help to understand.*

---

So, to solve this design problem, I want write a Twisted TCP server that will be like a pool of long-running-processes. Each of long-running-processes is a small Twisted TCP server that gives an access to one copy of the C-program.

In example, a user ask the pool-server to reserve a long-running-process for him, then the pool-server create and run a long-running-process that starts listening on some port, then the pool-server return the host and port of this long-running-process to user. Now, user can communicate with this long-running-process directly.

---

**Questions**

1. How start these long-running-process from the pool-server? The pool-server and each of long-running-processes are should be separate Twisted servers.
2. Is Twisted a good choice for these aims?
3. Maybe there are another ways how solve this design problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Twisted for this sounds like it makes sense.  The low-level API that supports running processes in Twisted is [reactor.spawnProcess](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.html).  Some examples of its usage are given in the [process howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) document.

This API is well suited for dealing with many long running processes, and as with all I/O APIs in Twisted, it works well when combined with another event source, such as [a web server](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html) users can use to request new processes be started up.

`reactor.spawnProcess` is more like the standard library subprocess module than like the `multiprocessing` package.  It gives you a way to launch a child process running a particular executable, with particular arguments, etc.  It does not provide a high-level API for running a particular Python function in another process.  However, it's not too hard to build such a thing (at least for a particular case).  Consider this approach:

```
from sys import executable
from os import environ

from twisted.internet import reactor

implementation = """\
from yourapp import somefunction
somefunction()
"""

reactor.spawnProcess(executable, [executable, "-c", implementation], env=environ)
reactor.run()
```

This just launches a new Python interpreter (whichever one you happen to be running) and uses the -c option to specify a program on the command line for it to run.

Comment: Okay, the reactors in the pool-server and in a long-running-process will be different, won't be it?

Comment: I didn't find an example or documentation about how to spawn a process like `p = Process(target=function_name); p.start();` in _multiprocessing_ module.

Comment: There's typically exactly one reactor.  I updated the answer to address the *multiprocessing* comparison.